# Comparing Availability and Booked Events to count the number of minutes available in a day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query that will tell me which days have  minutes available to book an appointment. I have two tables, `availabilities` and `events`.

The `availabilities` and `events` table both store: the start time `start_time`, end time `end_time` and user id `user_id`.

I have tried to join `events` to the `availabilities` table, then finding the difference between the event times and availabilities for the total number of minutes available. If there isn't an event overlapping the availability then `availability.start_time` and `availability.end_time` are compared.

This will only work if there is only one event that overlaps the availability. If multiple events overlap the availability, then each event if not taken into account when finding the difference.

```sql
WITH merged_availabilities AS (
  SELECT
    availabilities.id,
    COALESCE(
      (SELECT TRUE WHERE (events.id IS NULL) AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM availabilities.end_time - availabilities.start_time)::int / 60 >= 45),
      (SELECT TRUE WHERE (NOT events.id IS NULL)AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM availabilities.end_time - events.end_time)::int / 60 >= 45),
      (SELECT TRUE WHERE (NOT events.id IS NULL) AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM events.start_time - availabilities.start_time)::int / 60 >= 45)
    ) as "available"
  FROM
    availabilities
  LEFT JOIN
    events
    ON
      tsrange(availabilities.start_time, availabilities.end_time) && tsrange(events.start_time, events.end_time)
)

SELECT
  merged_availabilities.id,
  merged_availabilities.available
FROM
  merged_availabilities
```

[image: cell example]

Considering the image above, where each cell represents 15 minutes of time (traveling from left to right). The tops row shows 4 booked events and the bottom row shows 2 blocks of availability (the first is 45 minutes long, the second is 30 minutes long, with a break of 15 minutes in between).

My pgSQL would say that both availability blocks have 15 minutes still available, even though the second is fully booked because over events aren't considered when finding the differences.

Only the first availability block is available.

Edit:

Table Structure

`availabilities`

```
id int,
start_time timestamp,
end_time timestamp
```

`events`

```
id int,
start_time timestamp,
end_time timestamp
```

Sample data

`availabilities`

```
1, 2019-07-10 09:00:00, 2019-07-10 12:00:00
2, 2019-07-10 13:00:00, 2019-07-10 17:30:00
3, 2019-07-11 09:00:00, 2019-07-10 12:00:00
4, 2019-07-11 13:00:00, 2019-07-10 17:30:00
5, 2019-07-13 09:00:00, 2019-07-10 12:00:00
```

`events`

```
1, 2019-07-10 09:00:00, 2019-07-10 09:45:00
2, 2019-07-10 09:45:00, 2019-07-10 10:30:00
3, 2019-07-10 10:30:00, 2019-07-10 11:30:00
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and table structure and desired output

Comment: Unrelated, but: `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM availabilities.end_time - availabilities.start_time)::int / 60 >= 45` can be simplified to `end_time - availabilities.start_time >= interval '45 minute'`

Comment: @jimmy8ball I've just updated my question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name much simpler, thanks

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, you need to see how many minutes from the available time is remaining after the event total has been worked out for each id?

Comment: Yeah, that's is. I need to minus the total length of all events in a day, from the amount of availability in a day. If that's greater than  (45 in my SQL example) then return true

Comment: @jimmy8ball update on the above:  The time left must be in a single block though (>= 45), and not multiple small intervals that total 45 mins

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

A combination of a  SUBQUERY, the DATE_PART function, a SUM, and a CASE STATEMENT to flag the ID's that have >=45 mins remaining.

The solution assumes your ID's in your events table are FOREIGN KEYS and can appear more than once, and that your ID's in your availabilities table is a PRIMARY KEY.

Using this ID, it is possible to calculate the total minutes in the session and offset the calculated total event minutes from each event time.

```
SELECT
   av.id,
   av.start_time,
   av.end_time,
   DATE_PART('hour', start_time - end_time) * 60 +
   DATE_PART('minute',  start_time - end_time) AS session_mins_available,
   COALESCE(TOTAL_MIN_USED,0) AS TOTAL_MIN_USED,
   DATE_PART('hour', start_time - end_time) * 60 +
   DATE_PART('minute',  start_time - end_time) - COALESCE(TOTAL_MIN_USED,0) AS MINUTES_AVAILABLE,
   CASE WHEN DATE_PART('hour', start_time - end_time) * 60 +
             DATE_PART('minute',  start_time - end_time) - COALESCE(TOTAL_MIN_USED,0)
   <=-45 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS FLAG
FROM availabilities av
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
       e.id,
       SUM(MINUSED) AS TOTAL_MIN_USED
    FROM
       (SELECT
       E.id,
       E.start_time,
       E.next_start_time,
       E.end_time,
       DATE_PART('hour', start_time - COALESCE(next_start_time, end_time)) * 60 +
       DATE_PART('minute',  start_time - COALESCE(next_start_time, end_time)) AS MINUSED
       FROM
       (SELECT e.start_time, 
           lead(e.start_time) over (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.start_time) as next_start_time, 
           e.end_time,
           e.id
        FROM events e
       )E
      )e
   GROUP BY e.id
 )EVENTTIMES
 ON av.id = EVENTTIMES.id
```

Because time between events is being disregarded as potential availability, the measure for the total minutes used in the session needs to be calculated from the preceding event start time to the next event start time.

```
   DATE_PART('hour', start_time - COALESCE(next_start_time, end_time)) * 60 +
   DATE_PART('minute',  start_time - COALESCE(next_start_time, end_time)) AS MINUSED
```

The LEAD function has been used to bring the next event start time relative to each ID, onto the same row as the preceding event start time.

When there is no next event start time the event time is calculated to the event end time.

```
 COALESCE(next_start_time, end_time)
```

Finally adding a case statement will flag the availabilities ID's where total mins remaining >=45

Comment: close, but a series of 5-minute gaps between events could add up to the total required time (e.g. 45 minutes), marking the date as having availability

Comment: Yes, I see the issue, I think the best approach therefore, if you are disregarding the minutes between events, the measure needs to be taken from the event start time to next event start time as the individual event time, this way the minutes between events will not show as availability. I will update

Comment: that sounds like it will work. Looking forward to seeing your update

Comment: does this run for you? I get a few reference errors, running on PSQL 11. The first error is `missing FROM-clause entry for table "events"` line 11. Then after debugging, I get a few more

Comment: @JamesJohnson - I think it was simply that I hadn't double quoted the SEQ, should be ok now, I have changed to AS "SEQ"

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't run, `column events.seq does not exist` on line 23

Comment: @JamesJohnson - updated to use LEAD, following feedback from the communityabout the use of ROW_NUMBER, a simpler method was to use the LEAD function. tested and compiled in PGAdmin